# Sorting vector based on tuple value

Tags: c++, stl

I have below data structure,

```
typedef vector< tuple<int,int,int> > vector_tuple;
```

In vector i am storing `tuple<value,count,position>`

I want to sort my vector based on count, If count is same then based on position sort the vector.

```
structure ordering
{
  bool ordering()(....)
  {
    return /// ?
  }

};
int main()
{ 
    std::vector<int> v1{1,1,1,6,6,5,4,4,5,5,5};
    std::vector<int> v2(v1);
    vector_tuple vt;
    std::tuple<int,int,int> t1;
    std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
    int sizev=v1.size();
    for(int i=0; i < sizev ; i++)
    {
         auto countnu = count(begin(v2),end(v2),v1[i]);  
         if(countnu > 0)
         {
           v2.erase(std::remove(begin(v2),end(v2),v1[i]),end(v2));
           auto t = std::make_tuple(v1[i], countnu, i);
           vt.push_back(t);
         }
     }
     sort(begin(vt),end(vt),ordering(get<1>vt); // I need to sort based on count and if count is same, sort based on position.


     for (int i=0; i < vt.size(); i++)
     {

        cout << get<0>(vt[i]) << " " ;
        cout << get<1>(vt[i]) << " " ;
        cout << get<2>(vt[i]) << " \n" ;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your compare method should look like:

```
auto ordering = [](const std::tuple<int, int, int>& lhs,
                   const std::tuple<int, int, int>& rhs) {
    return std::tie(std::get<1>(lhs), std::get<2>(lhs))
         < std::tie(std::get<1>(rhs), std::get<2>(rhs));
};

std::sort(std::begin(vt), std::end(vt), ordering);
```

Comment: Always prefer `std::tie` to hand-rolled comparison functions. It always results in 100% correct and optimal code. +1

Answer (score 3):

All credit to Jarod42 for the `std::tie` answer.

Now let's make it generic by creating a variadic template predicate:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
struct tuple_parts_ascending
{
    template<class...Ts>
    static auto sort_order(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
    {
        return std::tie(std::get<Is>(t)...);
    }

    template<class...Ts>
    bool operator()(const std::tuple<Ts...>& l,
                    const std::tuple<Ts...>& r) const
    {
        return sort_order(l) < sort_order(r);
    }
};
```

which we can invoke thus:

```
sort(begin(vt),end(vt),tuple_parts_ascending<1,2>());
```

Full Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector< std::tuple<int,int,int> > vector_tuple;

template<std::size_t...Is>
struct tuple_parts_ascending
{
    template<class...Ts>
    static auto sort_order(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
    {
        return std::tie(std::get<Is>(t)...);
    }

    template<class...Ts>
    bool operator()(const std::tuple<Ts...>& l,
                    const std::tuple<Ts...>& r) const
    {
        return sort_order(l) < sort_order(r);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1,1,1,6,6,5,4,4,5,5,5};
    std::vector<int> v2(v1);
    vector_tuple vt;
    std::tuple<int,int,int> t1;
    std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
    int sizev=v1.size();
    for(int i=0; i < sizev ; i++)
    {
        auto countnu = count(begin(v2),end(v2),v1[i]);
        if(countnu > 0)
        {
            v2.erase(std::remove(begin(v2),end(v2),v1[i]),end(v2));
            auto t = std::make_tuple(v1[i], countnu, i);
            vt.push_back(t);
        }
    }
    sort(begin(vt),end(vt),tuple_parts_ascending<1,2>());


    for (int i=0; i < vt.size(); i++)
    {

        cout << get<0>(vt[i]) << " " ;
        cout << get<1>(vt[i]) << " " ;
        cout << get<2>(vt[i]) << " \n" ;
    }

}
```

Expected results:

```
6 2 3
4 2 6
1 3 0
5 4 5
```

Going further, we could make this operation a little more generic and 'library-worthy' by allowing the ordering predicate and the indices to be passed as parameters (this solution required c++14):

```
namespace detail {
    template<class Pred, std::size_t...Is>
    struct order_by_parts
    {
        constexpr
        order_by_parts(Pred&& pred)
        : _pred(std::move(pred))
        {}

        template<class...Ts>
        constexpr
        static auto sort_order(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
        {
            return std::tie(std::get<Is>(t)...);
        }

        template<class...Ts>
        constexpr
        bool operator()(const std::tuple<Ts...>& l,
                        const std::tuple<Ts...>& r) const
        {
            return _pred(sort_order(l), sort_order(r));
        }

    private:
        Pred _pred;
    };
}

template<class Pred, size_t...Is>
constexpr
auto order_by_parts(Pred&& pred, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using pred_type = std::decay_t<Pred>;
    using functor_type = detail::order_by_parts<pred_type, Is...>;
    return functor_type(std::forward<Pred>(pred));
}
```

Now we can sort like so:

```
sort(begin(vt),end(vt),
     order_by_parts(std::less<>(),                  // use predicate less<void>
                    std::index_sequence<1, 2>()));  // pack indices into a sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lambdas:

```
std::sort(std::begin(vt),std::end(vt),[](const auto& l,const auto& r){
    if(std::get<1>(l)== std::get<1>(r)){
         return std::get<2>(l) < std::get<2>(r);
    }
    return std::get<1>(l) < std::get<1>(r);
});
```